# In Zcash, how does a recipient look up which transactions belong to him/her?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, cryptocurrency

For Monero, the scheme for stealth addresses is pretty straightforward. (For example: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/what-is-a-stealth-address) However, I haven't found any details on how the same functionality is done in Zcash, can someone provide more information on this?

Comment: https://github.com/zcash/zips/blob/main/protocol/protocol.pdf

Comment: @knaccc Hi, I know this document, but is there anywhere an intuitive explanation regarding how it's different from Monero's stealth address system? I just want to know if they use the similar ECC mechanisms, or if it's very different.